# Angularjs - should I use forEach or Filter?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app that returns a collection called `users`.  I am using it to populate a dropdown using `ng-options`.  Within the collection I have a field called `temp_number` and another called `number`.

What I am looking to do is to check to see if each record has a `temp_number` value and if so, assign that to `number` in the DOM.

Is this something I would be better doing with `.forEach` within my controller where I return the collection initially? or as a custom filter somehow within the `ng-option`?

Thanks!

Comment: If you only want to display the `number`s that have a `temp_number`, then use filter in your controller. If you want to show every `number` either way, use a regular foreach.

Comment: i would personally doing this using filter() much explicative and performing

Comment: Thanks all.  What I would like to display is `number` unless there is a `temp_number`.